# postgresql create one row from two

Tags: postgresql

I have a 2 rows like this:

```
device    ip            port    vlan  network
---------------------------------------------
device a  ip_address a  port_a  vlan  network
device b  ip_address b  port_b  vlan  network
```

As you can see, 2 devices can share vlan and network (point-to-point network) and some devices can have only one network and vlan and doesn't share it with any other (access network)

I want to get at final like this:

```
 device_a;device_b;network;ip_address_a;ip_address_b;port_a;port_b;vlan
```

I am new at Postgres and I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
select string_agg(distinct device,';') || 
        ';' || string_agg(distinct network,';') || 
        ';' || string_agg(distinct ip,';') ||
        ';' || string_agg(distinct port,';') || 
        ';' || string_agg(distinct vlan,';') 
from your_table
```

Here's a small sample to illustrate this method:

```
 with dt as (
    select 'device_a'::text col1, 'network'::text col2
    union all
    select 'device_b'::text col1, 'network'::text col2
)
select string_agg(distinct col1,';') || 
        ';' || string_agg(distinct col2,';') 
from dt
```

EDIT: Simplified thanks to a_horse_with_no_name.